# Does shared_preferences stored setting/ properties/ data still exist after user update a new version of the app?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

e.g. app v1.0 stored some user settings through shared_preferences plug-in,
then app v1.1 is published in App Store and Play Store, and user updated to app v1.1,
do those customized settings still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the shared preferences survive app updates.